# Problems with NSolve[] finding zeros of a 32-degree polynomial

Tags: numerics, polynomials, equation-solving

I have the following calculation in Mathematica:

```
part16a = 
  Sum[(z^(s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5 + s6 + s7 + s8 + s9 + s10 + s11 + 
        s12 + s13 + s14 + s15 + s16))*(b^(s1*s2 + s2*s3 + s3*s4 + 
        s1*s5 + s2*s6 + s3*s7 + s4*s8 + s5*s6 + s6*s7 + s7*s8 + 
        s5*s9 + s6*s10 + s7*s11 + s8*s12 + s9*s10 + s10*s11 + 
        s11*s12 + s9*s13 + s10*s14 + s11*s15 + s12*s16 + s13*s14 + 
        s14*s15 + s15*s16 + s1*s13 + s2*s14 + s3*s15 + s4*s16 + 
        s1*s4 + s5*s8 + s9*s12 + s13*s16)),
        {s1, -1, 1, 2}, {s2, -1, 1, 2}, {s3, -1, 1, 2}, {s4, -1, 1, 
    2}, {s5, -1, 1, 2}, {s6, -1, 1, 2}, {s7, -1, 1, 2}, {s8, -1, 1, 
    2}, {s9, -1, 1, 2}, {s10, -1, 1, 2}, {s11, -1, 1, 2}, {s12, -1, 1,
     2}, {s13, -1, 1, 2}, {s14, -1, 1, 2}, {s15, -1, 1, 2}, {s16, -1, 
    1, 2}];
part16 = Collect[Expand[(z^16)*part16a], z]
part100 = part16 /. {b -> 1/100};
solutions100 = NSolve[part100 == 0, z, WorkingPrecision -> 196];
NumberForm[list100 = z /. solutions100, 24]
NumberForm[list100h = (Log[z]/Log[1/100]) /. solutions100, 24]
ListPlot[Table[{Re[Part[list100, i]], Im[Part[list100, i]]}, {i, 32}],
  AspectRatio -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3*10^8, 3*10^8}, {-3*10^8, 3*10^8}}]  
ListPlot[Table[{Re[Part[list100h, i]], Im[Part[list100h, i]]}, {i, 
   32}], PlotRange -> {{-4.4, 4.4}, {-0.6, 0.6}}, 
 PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[4]]
```

The first part generates an expression in the variable b and z, no problem. I want to set a value for b and then find the zeros of the remaining expression, which will be a polynomial in z. In the code above I have let b->1/100. Since this is an expression from statistical mechanics I have some idea what the general placement of the zeros will be in the complex z-plane. For b->1/100 everything works fine. There are 32 zeros, 16 are of a very small value and 16 of a very large value. One of my plots shows 16 of the large values and the 16 small values are indicated by a dot at  the origin.

Trouble arrives when I evaluate for b->1/1000000 or other very small value of b. My obvious thought is simply increase the WorkingPrecision and these problems will go away. I have increased WorkingPrecision to around 1800 figures and I know I am not getting all the correct values. Now for example there is not an even distribution between large and small values. One of the zeros now appears as a multiple zero but I know this is not the case.

I can only guess the problem arises because of the extreme values of the coefficients but I would think that would be taken care of by WorkingPrecision.

Any and all suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `N[Solve[eqn, z]]` or `N[Solve[eqn, z], 20]` instead?

Comment: Thanks! Fantastic! this works but I don't really understand exactly why. That is I thought that the most straightforward way to find the zeros of a polynomial was using NSolve[], and that it would give the full 32 correct zeros that go along with any 32 degree polynomial. It certainly works with some values of b but not when b is very, very small. Solve[] somehow must does a better job.                        Thanks again